# KeyError: 'name' in JSON file

Tags: python, json, csv

When I try to write from the JSON file I get the following ValueError only with "name". The error I get is located in the line just before
if **name** == "**main**":
If I change the value for example "num_holdouts" there is no Error:

```
writer.writerow([playlist["pid"], playlist["name"], "0", "0"])
```

KeyError: 'name'

Here is a part of the JSON file:

```json
{
    "date": "2018-01-16 08:47:28.198015", 
    "version": "v1", 
    "playlists": [
        {
            "name": "spanish playlist", 
            "num_holdouts": 11, 
            "pid": 1000002, 
            "num_tracks": 11, 
            "tracks": [], 
            "num_samples": 0
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Groovin", 
            "num_holdouts": 48, 
            "pid": 1000003, 
            "num_tracks": 48, 
            "tracks": [], 
            "num_samples": 0
        }, 
        {
            "name": "uplift", 
            "num_holdouts": 40, 
            "pid": 1000004, 
            "num_tracks": 40, 
            "tracks": [], 
            "num_samples": 0
        }, 
        {
            "name": "WUBZ", 
            "num_holdouts": 27, 
            "pid": 1000006, 
            "num_tracks": 27, 
            "tracks": [], 
            "num_samples": 0
        }, 
        {
            "name": "new", 
            "num_holdouts": 41, 
            "pid": 1000007, 
            "num_tracks": 41, 
            "tracks": [], 
            "num_samples": 0
        },
```

Here is the code:

```py
import json
import os
import csv

def process_playlists(path):
    filenames = os.listdir(path)
    with open('challenge_set_data.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as accounts:
        writer=csv.writer(accounts)

        for filename in sorted(filenames):
            if filename.startswith("challenge_set") and filename.endswith(".json"):
                fullpath = os.sep.join((path, filename))
                f = open(fullpath)
                js = f.read()
                f.close()
                mpd_slice = json.loads(js)
                writer.writerow(["pid", "playlist_name", "track_uri", "track_name"])
                for playlist in mpd_slice["playlists"]:

                    if playlist["tracks"] == []:

                        writer.writerow([playlist["pid"], playlist["name"], "0", "0"])

                    else:
                        for i, track in enumerate(playlist["tracks"]):

                            tracks=("[%3d %s - %s - ]" % (i + 1, track["track_name"],track["track_uri"]))

                            writer.writerow([playlist["pid"], playlist["name"], track["track_uri"],track["track_name"]])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Datasets\\chall_set"
    process_playlists(path)
```

Comment: Are some entries in this JSON file missing a "name" attribute? I would bet that's what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to save a small part of the file and there is no problem.